# "crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password" when trying to compare passwords for login

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a login function in my Go application.
I have a register function which uses `bcrypt` to hash the password so I can store it in the database.

The user is registered successfully and I have the hashed password in the database.
When trying to log in, I try to compare the hashed password from the database with the plain text password I get in the request.
However, I always get this error:

```
crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password
```

I checked, and I get both, the hashed password from the database and the plain text one from the request correctly.
Using

```
err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(userInfo.fetchedPassword), []byte(password))
```

`fetchedPassword` is the hashed password from the database and `password` is the password I get from the request.
I always get the same result. I saw a post about this that created like 4 years ago, but without an answer.

Hashed Password generation:

```
func hashPassword(password string) ([]byte, error) {
    hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return hashedPassword, nil
}
```

Retriving password from database:

```
type info struct {
    fetchedEmail    string
    fetchedPassword string
}

var userInfo info

row := db.QueryRow("SELECT email, password FROM users where email=$1", email)
err := row.Scan(&userInfo.fetchedEmail, &userInfo.fetchedPassword)
fmt.Println(userInfo.fetchedPassword)

if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(userInfo.fetchedPassword), []byte(password))
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
```

For setting the password in the database, I just take the hashedPassword and with SQL `INSERT` command inserting it with the rest of the information about the user.

Comment: Please show your code to generate the hash, store it, and retrieve it.

Comment: @Marc I added the request info.

Comment: A quick glance shows nothing wrong. I recommend you write some unit tests that exercise generation/storage/retrieval/comparison. It could still be the way you store the password (DB schema and type) or the way you read in the password (http post or other). You can post details of those, but you should still write those tests.

Comment: @Marc thanks, I will write tests eventually but I kinda need to understand why it does not work properly first.

Comment: Writing tests as you're writing your code is usually the best way to figure that out. But you can also provide more details here (schema, how the password is passed in).

Comment: This code looks correct to me too. You should log the hash before you store it and after you retrieve it and make sure that it hasn't changed along the way somewhere (use fmt.Printf with the "%q" verb so whitespace and potentially unprintable characters are visible). And obviously double and tripple check the password, but I guess you already did that.

Comment: @RobNapier, nope: https://play.golang.org/p/uRJ3LCSqeCH

Comment: @Peter Thanks. I forgot that the output of bcrypt is ASCII (unlike PBKDF2, SHA-2, and all the others). That does narrow the problem quite a lot. Thanks. (Deleted comments to avoid confusion from future readers.)

Comment: @Peter thanks, I did printed out the results, on login and on registering, everything looks correct.

Comment: Ensure your DB schema is wide enough to store a large hash. Also maybe your DB is doing some odd string encoding. I'd echo Peter's comments: `log.Printf("hashfromDB: %q", hashFromDB)` to show any rogue (unprintable) bytes that the DB may be storing.

Comment: @colm.anseo Thanks, I set the column in the database to be varchar, I'm using Postgres and varchar is unlimited in length. I logged the hashed password when generating it, when registering the user and when getting it from the database, and they are all the same.

Comment: Test your assumptions. The code you have posted above works: https://play.golang.org/p/eIK0mbbfE3w That means you have a problem elsewhere - probably somewhere in the storage/retrieval step. Replace saving to the db with storing in memory and test the result immediately. Beware that your hash func returns a byte array, and you're using a string type in the db, then reading back as string, that may be the problem.

Comment: If I had to guess - I'd say the user input password (during registration) is not being captured accurately. I would in-the-clear log the password pre-hashing to verify absolutely that the password being saved is the password you expect (post-hashing its impossible to tell).

Comment: @colm.anseo Thank you so much! I printed the hashedPassword in my register function so many times and totally forgot about the not hashedPassword, it actually was it. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Return a `string` for your hash password instead a byte.

```
func HashPassword(password string) (string, error) {
    bytes, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), 14)
    return string(bytes), err
}

func CheckPassword(password, hash string) bool {
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hash), []byte(password))
    return err == nil
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, merely a suggestion (which does not help). This should be a comment on the question.

Comment: That is still not an answer, but a suggestion of something to try. There is nothing wrong with using the returned byte slice and as the OP said, using a string does not solve anything.

Comment: @Marc i can't add comment into that question because i am new contributor so i post on answer !!

Comment: Posting a non-answer is not going to help. Contribute on SO until you reach 50 reputation and you will be able to post comments.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it